# stop function running if selector does not exist - jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stop my autoBike(); bike function running if my `#bike-main-slider div.bike` data-bike attribute value does not exist.

```
<script>

    var bike = '<?=(isset($_REQUEST['bike']) ? htmlentities($_REQUEST['bike']) : null)?>';

    autoBike = function () {

         var bikeIndex = $('#bike-main-slider div.bike[data-bike=' + bike + ']').index();

         mainSlider.goToSlide(bikeIndex);  

    };

    autoBike();

</script>

<div id="slideshow">

     <div class="bike" data-bike="50cc"></div>
     <div class="bike" data-bike="100cc"></div>
     <div class="bike" data-bike="150cc"></div>
     <div class="bike" data-bike="200cc"></div>
     <div class="bike" data-bike="250cc"></div>
     <div class="bike" data-bike="350cc"></div>

</div>
```

Is this possible?

So for example if my URL is...

**http://example.com/?bike=450cc**

and as you can see no 450cc exists in my #slideshow divs, so is there anyway to prevent my `autoBike();` function running if data-bike attribute value does not exist?

Using jQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
autoBike = function () {
     var $bike = $('#bike-main-slider div.bike[data-bike=' + bike + ']');
     if($bike.size() > 0) {
          var bikeIndex = $bike.index();
          mainSlider.goToSlide(bikeIndex); 
     }
};
```

Comment: I suggest you use .length instead of .size(). They do pretty much the same thing but that way you don't have a function overhead.

Comment: I tried this with lenght and it does not work? Why is using .size a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of the object returned when calling the selector and if zero, simply return from the function the first thing you do.

```
var autobike = function () {

   var elms = $('#bike-main-slider div.bike[data-bike=' + bike + ']');
   if (elms.length === 0)
       return;

   // Do your stuff here, at least one element matched.
}
```

Here is a working example with the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/Gp5Xw/

**length-property vs. jQuery's .size()**

As calling the jQuery function with a selector will return an array, that array will have a length-property that you can read, as any other JavaScript array. Using jQuery's `.size()` method will produce the same result as reading the length property, but it require an additional function call, which is totally unnecessary. It's a micro-optimization to use the length-property really, but still.

From the jQuery documentation of [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/):

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, **the .length property is preferred** because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Weirdly I was still getting the effect that I was originally with this. I've never used length before but maybe I was making a mistake somewhere. The above answer seemed to work for me. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Joshc Above code should work, added a working example as a fiddle. Also elaborated a bit more on why you should use the length-property instead of `.size()`

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var bike = '<?=(isset($_REQUEST['bike']) ? htmlentities($_REQUEST['bike']) : null)?>';

$('bike').each(function() {
 if ($(this).attr('data-bike') === bike) {
     autoBike();
 }
});

});
```

autoBike() will then only run, if your URL parameter for bike exists as an data-bike attribute...